# Importing a certificate and granting permissions on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

On Windows 2012 R2, winhttpcertcfg -i FileName -a CertAccount -c LOCAL_MACHINE\MY -p Password installs the certificate on Trusted Root Store instead of LOCAL_MACHINE\MY. I also need to grant access to the private key to an account specified by the -a option. Is there a way to achieve the same using Powershell / CertUtil ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winhttpcertcfg does not import certificates correctly on Server 2008 R2 and onwards.
The download page says it is compatible upto Server 2003.
See

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19801

The alternative command is certutil.

http://technet.microsoft.com/library/cc732443.aspx

What is missing is a tool that takes arguments like Winhttpcertcfg that can take a parameter to which store you want to install to. Certutil cannot do that.

See answer by jaspernygaard

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171117/import-pfx-file-into-particular-certificate-store-from-command-line

Winhttpcertcfg does allow granting access to accounts which certutil does not do and it works on Server 2008 R2 to Server 2012 R2 via the -g parameter.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662329.aspx

The only option to import a certificate and grant permissions to an account is using Powershell. See Answer by mao47 for simple import of certificate using Powershell

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171117/import-pfx-file-into-particular-certificate-store-from-command-line

See answer for importing and granting access using Powershell
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852807/setting-private-key-permissions-with-powershell

If you want to write a tool then use C#

See

http://www.codeproject.com/script/Forums/View.aspx?fid=1649&msg=2062983

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337721/how-to-programmatically-install-a-certificate-using-c-sharp